# Outputting Firebase database data to webpage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to output all the data from my Firebase Database to a blank webpage. I currently have it printing out in the chrome console using the code below.
    
    `ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    }, function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.code);
    });`

Instead of it printing to the console I want it to print to the actual webpage itself. Struggling since there is not much documentation around Firebase itself.
Here is my entire code for the near blank html page im trying to output the Firebase database data to. I have also included a picture of the structure of my Firebase database.[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAMYm.png)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>  
<script src = "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase-app.js">
</script>
<script src = "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase-auth.js">
</script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase-database.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/membrain.ico">


<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>

<script>
    const config = {

    .........
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Firebase Database</h1>

            <script>
            var ref = firebase.database().ref();

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
console.log(snapshot.val());
}, function (error) {
 console.log("Error: " + error.code);
});




</script>
</body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Please go ahead and try it yourself first. Community will be happy to help you with your problems.